# set view frame using picture size ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

how do I init a view without setting its frame?

my designer gave me a bunch of images,i can figure out the position of those on screen, but what about the size? is there a way to set the view's frame using the picture's original size instead of specify it everytime?

thanks for any hint !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what kind of view is it? You can use a `UIImageView` if you want.

I think `UIImageView` has an `initWithImage:` method that does what you want...

Just pass in your image as a `UIImage` into the `initWithImage:` method and it should fix the frame size depending on the image you supplied...

Comment: how about just UIView? is possible?

Comment: I think a UIImageView inherits from UIView (so it's actually a UIView practically).
But if you insist, you can use a UIImageView INSIDE a UIView and then do the above.

Comment: how about UIButtons? can I just set its image without setting frame? so it'll have same size as image

Comment: if you check the reference of `UIButton`, you can see that this is possible. Hint: methods like `setImage:ForState:` sound like they would do the job, wouldn't they? You should get familiar with Apple's reference docs (it will help you tackle almost ANY problem). Just use them whenever you have a question like this...

Comment: [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) is a link to the UIButton reference. BTW, it also inherits from UIView (like UIImageView).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this -

```
 UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xorigin,yorigin, x, 
   y)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
```

And if you want to set an image to button then you can use this code -

```
  [btnName setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And without giving frame you can also set image. It automatically takes the size.